# Ajax stop working when using p:messages with conditional rendering

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Environment: JBoss EAP 6.3, Mojarra 2.1.28, JSF 2.0 and java 1.7.0_79.

On my xhtml template I have two p:messages as below, used to display global messages:

```
<p:messages
    id="globalMessages"
    globalOnly="true"
    autoUpdate="true"
    severity="fatal, error, warn"
    rendered="#{menuMB.renderFatalErrorWarningMessage}" />
<p:messages
    id="globalMessagesInfo"
    globalOnly="true"
    autoUpdate="true"
    severity="info"
    rendered="#{menuMB.renderInfoMessage}" />
```

On MenuMB I have

```
@Inject
private FacesContext facesContext;

public boolean isRenderInfoMessage() {
    return facesContext.getMaximumSeverity() == null || facesContext.getMaximumSeverity().equals(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
}

public boolean isRenderFatalErrorWarningMessage() {
    return !isRenderInfoMessage();
}
```

On my page that uses the template, I have several fields with their respective p:message for error handling, e.g.

```
<h:inputText id="firstName" />
<p:message for="firstName" />
```

If I submit the form and validation fails on field firstName, the local message is presented as expected. However, from this moment on, ajax calls no longer work.

If I change MenuMB methods to not use FacesContext

```
public boolean isRenderInfoMessage() {
    // return facesContext.getMaximumSeverity() == null || facesContext.getMaximumSeverity().equals(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
    return true;
}

public boolean isRenderFatalErrorWarningMessage() {
    // return !isRenderInfoMessage();
    return false;
}
```

, all ajax calls keep working as expected. The same whether I remove rendered option from p:messages or I set rendered=true/false (no method call).

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Also I can't see any JavaScript error on firebug console

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find an exception somewhere is occurring that's stopping all future calls, most likely a potential java-script issue.

Also from memory, you don't need to wrap a p:messages in a rendered tag - it automatically only renders if there is content in the specified severity you define.

A gotchya with targeted rendering is that the value has to be on the page already for it to be targeted, so targeting an attribute that may not be rendered will fail. It's best to wrap sed attributes in another tag you can target and then it will load the inner content renders.

Comment: I have two distinct p:messages because I have a situation where both a success (info) and an error messages are triggered at same time and, in this case, I want only the error message to be displayed...

Comment: I also tried moving the rendered option to a surrounding a4j:outputPanel, but the error remains the same. Looks like it is specific to the test I do on MenuMB using FacesContext.

Comment: What's the scope of MenuMB?

Comment: It is SessionScoped

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to solve my problem was by overriding class MessagesRenderer from primefaces:

```
package xx.xx.xx.PFMessagesRenderer;

import org.primefaces.component.messages.MessagesRenderer;

public class PFMessagesRenderer extends MessagesRenderer {
    @Override
    public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        Messages uiMessages = (Messages) component;
        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        String clientId = uiMessages.getClientId(context);
        Map<String, List<FacesMessage>> messagesMap = new HashMap<String, List<FacesMessage>>();

        ////////////////////////////////////////
        // BEGIN CHANGES
        ////////////////////////////////////////
        boolean showInfoMessage = true;

        if (uiMessages.isGlobalOnly()) {
            Iterator<FacesMessage> messages = context.getMessages(null);
            boolean hasInfoMessage = false;
            boolean hasWarnErrorFatalMessage = false;

            while (messages.hasNext()) {
                if (messages.next().getSeverity().equals(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO)) {
                    hasInfoMessage = true;
                } else {
                    hasWarnErrorFatalMessage = true;
                }
            }

            if (hasInfoMessage && hasWarnErrorFatalMessage) {
                showInfoMessage = false;
            }
        }
        ////////////////////////////////////////
        // BEGIN CHANGES
        ////////////////////////////////////////

        String _for = uiMessages.getFor();
        Iterator<FacesMessage> messages;

        if (_for != null) {
            messages = context.getMessages(_for);
        } else {
            messages = uiMessages.isGlobalOnly() ? context.getMessages(null) : context.getMessages();
        }

        while (messages.hasNext()) {
            FacesMessage message = messages.next();
            FacesMessage.Severity severity = message.getSeverity();

            if (severity.equals(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO)) {
                ////////////////////////////////////////
                // BEGIN CHANGES
                ////////////////////////////////////////
                if (showInfoMessage) {
                    addMessage(uiMessages, message, messagesMap, "info");
                }
                ////////////////////////////////////////
                // END CHANGES
                ////////////////////////////////////////
            } else if (severity.equals(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN)) {
                addMessage(uiMessages, message, messagesMap, "warn");
            } else if (severity.equals(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR)) {
                addMessage(uiMessages, message, messagesMap, "error");
            } else if (severity.equals(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL)) {
                addMessage(uiMessages, message, messagesMap, "fatal");
            }
        }

        writer.startElement("div", uiMessages);
        writer.writeAttribute("id", clientId, "id");
        writer.writeAttribute("class", "ui-messages ui-widget", null);

        for (String severity : messagesMap.keySet()) {
            List<FacesMessage> severityMessages = messagesMap.get(severity);

            if (severityMessages.size() > 0) {
                encodeSeverityMessages(context, uiMessages, severity, severityMessages);
            }
        }

        writer.endElement("div");
    }
}
```

On faces-config.xml we need to add

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
        <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.MessagesRenderer</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>xx.xx.xx.PFMessagesRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

This way my template page can have a single p:messages as below:

```
<p:messages
    id="globalMessages"
    globalOnly="true"
    autoUpdate="true"
    severity="error, fatal, warn, info" />
```